# Opening Microsoft Access Database file (*accdb) in Python (Pandas Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access

I've got a `.zip` file located in the cloud, which contains a `.accdb` (MS Access Database) file, with multiple rows and columns.

I want to work with that `.accdb` file in Python, via Google Colab (preferably), but can't find a way to properly open and read the file.

I installed `pyodbc`, imported it via `import pyodbc as pyo`, and added a connection string:

```
cnnstr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=zip_file.zip"
)
```

with `zip_file.zip` being the original url of the dataset I am using, which contains the `.accdb` file.

However, when trying to connect it to the `pyo` by stating `cnn = pyo.connect(cnnstr)`, I get: `Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`.

That's pretty much what I could do overall, I just don't know where to look/what to do.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to point to full path of Access DB file likely outside of compressed files. Also, you need that ODBC driver installed on your machine. MS offers free download under *Microsoft Access Redistributable*. Not sure if it is possible to run outside a Windows environment.

Comment: Extract file from zip to local folder.

Comment: @Parfait , thank you for your response. Is that the only workaround? Really didn't want to deploy it locally because I was hoping to running it entirely from the cloud, gaining versatility. But, if it is the only way, I will. Thank you!

Comment: @June7, do you mean extracting it and downloading it to my computer, and then using that file to run it from Google Colab? Or just using my local computer (no Google Colab? Thank you!

Comment: Don't know Google Colab but from what I just read, I don't see how it can connect to Access db in a zip folder or otherwise in the 'cloud'. Search topic of interacting directly with Access db sitting in 'cloud' - not practical. Need something like SharePoint or Azure.

Comment: I have seen some discussions about Colab connecting to local db such as MySQL, nothing about Access.

Comment: @June7 thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I will keep trying, and upload any news.